# Unable to read Advanced Messaging in ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native, sms

How can we read the messages with Type `Advanced Messaging`?

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-sms-android and it is only retrieving messages with Type `Text Message`

See the screenshots of both type of the messages.

[Screenshot of Advanced Messaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsWQW.jpg) [Screenshot of Text Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJIn6.jpg)

Comment: May be there is "type" key in the filter to get particular data

Comment: @NensiKasundra, I checked but not found any filter with "type" key, even in the Native Java code.

Comment: will check and let you know